# Create an 2D matrix coordinate (arrays) with null values

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to make an 2D 4x4 array of coordinates `(X, Y)` that its position on the array holds null values. Like `main_matrix[0][0] = null ... main_matrix[4, 4] = null` but I can't figure how I make this.
I would appreciate this prototype because I want to remake an 2048.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a function that creates an array and fills if with values, optionally using a callback, and use that to create the array of arrays:

```
function createArray(len, value) {
  var a = new Array(len), f = typeof value == "function";
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) a[i] = f ? value() : value;
  return a;
}

var main_matrix = createArray(4, createArray.bind(this, 4, null));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
main_matrix=[];
for(var i=0;i<4;i++){
    main_matrix[i]=[];
    for(var j=0;j<4;j++){
        main_matrix[i][j]=null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this implementation:

```
Array.apply(null, Array(2048)).map(function() { return Array.apply(null, Array(2048)).map(function() { return null }) });
```

Good luck